# How to enforce "User must change password at next logon" on Linux domain member?

Tags: linux, active-directory, authentication, password

I have an Ubuntu Server 18.04 domain member joined to Active Directory. Everything is working well, except for getting the AD ***User must change password at next login*** setting to be respected.

[image: Active Directory Users and Computers Reset Password dialog]

I want to force new users to change their temporary passwords upon first login, and this checkbox seems like the easiest way to do that. But when new users login, nothing happens. They just enter the session as normal and are not asked to make a new password.

I feel like there is a PAM setting for this, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Linux certainly supports this. How did you join the server to the domain?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need a tools like [sssd](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/windows_integration_guide/#SSSD-AD) to pass AD Password Policy or other AD GPO to linux clients. It is available on Ubuntu and almost all linux distros.

You can read more about this in the ubuntu site about [SSSD and Active Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html.en).

Answer (score 1):

Just do `sudo apt install libpam-krb5`
and then it obeys the "User must change password at next logon" group policy from windows AD

Comment: +1 for progress
`utest@eexmaple's password: **********
Your password has expired

But no further action is taken